# Using lists of primitive types in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

As EF can't save lists of primitive types, I have created a Day object that only  contains a enum from 1-7 and using migration seed method to fill the database. So in the database table I have the values 1 to 7.

```
public class Day
{
    [Key]
    public Days DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SalaryAddition> SalaryAdditions { get; set; }
}
```

I have set the connection between SalaryAddition and Day in my OnModelCreating.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SalaryAddition>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Days)
    .WithMany(s => s.SalaryAdditions)
    .Map(ss =>
    {
        ss.MapLeftKey("SalaryAdditionId");
        ss.MapRightKey("SalaryAdditionDay");
        ss.ToTable("SalaryAdditionDays");
    });
```

My problem is that for me to add a Day to my SalaryAddition object I need to load it from the database. But what I wanna is just do is something like this:

```
salaryAddition.Days.Add(new Day{DayOfWeek = Days.Monday});
```

*So I don't need to load a number with the number from the database.*

But when doing this I get:
`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Days'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Days'.`

Comment: Why not have a flag enum where each day is represented as a power of 2 and save that in `SalaryAddition` instead, as I would assume you would not want to map a `SalaryAddition` to the same day more than one.

Comment: That's sounds genius! But how would you do it in code?

Comment: I think this is a great suggestion, although the many-to-many would prevent duplicates too (each combination `SalaryAddition`, `Day` is unique).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use a flag enum I would think

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64,
    All = 127
}
```

Then in your `SalaryAddition` class you'd just have

```
public DaysOfWeek Days { get; set; }
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
if(salaryAddition.Days.HasFlag(DaysOfWeek.Monday))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This salary addition is linked to Monday");
}
```

And to set the flag for a day to it

```
salaryAddition.Days |= DaysOfWeek.Monday;
```

Or unset the flag

```
salaryAddition.Days &= ~DaysOfWeek.Monday;
```

Comment: I never used `Flags` before. But how do I add a day to a DaysOfWeek enum? something like `DaysOfWeek.Monday.Add(DaysOfWeek.Sunday)`? I can't plus them together.

Comment: Is this `var twoDays = DaysOfWeek.Monday | DaysOfWeek.Sunday` right ?

Comment: I've added the code for setting and unsetting individual flags.

Comment: @Jeggy There was an issue with the unsetting code that I've fixed.  Writing helper methods for setting and unsetting flags would not be a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's working now and here's my final code: http://pastebin.com/rSJ3GTf4

Comment: Sometimes we should be able to upvote twice. For answering and for improving.